# Gem install on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Try to install [feedzirra](http://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra) gem

Do this:

```
gem install pauldix-feedzirra
```

I get the following error:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pauldix-feedzirra:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for curl-config... no
checking for main() in -lcurl... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby
        --with-curl-dir
        --without-curl-dir
        --with-curl-include
        --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
        --with-curl-lib
        --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
        --with-curllib
        --without-curllib
extconf.rb:17:in `<main>':   Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)

  Try passing --with-curl-dir or --with-curl-lib and --with-curl-include
  options to extconf.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/taf2-curb-0.5.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/taf2-curb-0.5.4.0/ext/gem_make.out
```

**Ver:**

```
C:\Ruby192>gem -v
1.3.7

C:\Ruby192>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have **libcurl** installed:

```
checking for curl-config... no
checking for main() in -lcurl... no
```

Try this: [download it](http://www.gknw.net/mirror/curl/win32/curl-7.21.1-devel-mingw32.zip) and copy everything from the `bin` directory either to `C:\Windows\System32` or `%RUBY_ROOT%\bin`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download [Curl (binaries and devel)](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html). The problem you have is that it can't find the header files that usually are on devel packages.